# Get all Routes between two nodes neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a project where I have to deal with graphs...
I'm using a graph to get routes by bus and bike between two stops.

The fact is,all my relationship contains the time needed to go from the start point of the relationship and the end.

In order to get the shortest path between to node, I'm using the shortest path function of cypher. But something, the shortest path is not the fastest....

Is there a way to get all paths between two nodes not linked by a relationship?

Thanks

EDIT:

In fact I change my graph, to make it easier.
So I still have all my nodes. Now the relationship type correspond to the time needed to go from a node to another.

The shortestPath function of cypher give the path which contains less relationship. I would like that it returns the path where the addition of all Type (the time) is the smallest..
Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you required to use Cypher? I can think of some gremlin scripts that will print this out that should be pretty neat looking.

Comment: In fact I'm using nodeJs.. And I have a library to query my neo4j graph that allow me to do some cypher query ... and not gremlin query...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In cypher, to get all paths between two nodes not linked by a relationship, and sort by a total in a weight, you can use the reduce function introduced in 1.9:

```
start a=node(...), b=node(...) // get your start nodes
match p=a-[r*2..5]->b // match paths (best to provide maximum lengths to prevent queries from running away)
where not(a-->b) // where a is not directly connected to b
with p, relationships(p) as rcoll // just for readability, alias rcoll
return p, reduce(totalTime=0, x in rcoll: totalTime + x.time) as totalTime
order by totalTime
```

You can throw a limit 1 at the end, if you need only the shortest.

Comment: What do you mean by `getting all paths between two nodes not linked by a relationship` ? How can a path be formed between nodes if they aren't linked by relationships ?

Comment: Not linked directly, I meant. (also note, this is pretty old... syntax won't even run these days). Please see Apoc in 3.0 for some better ways to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Dijkstra/Astar algorithm, which seems to be a perfect fit for you. Take a look at http://api.neo4j.org/1.8.1/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html

Unfortunately you cannot use those from Cypher.

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing that.. I just wanted to know if there were a way to get all path between two nodes with cypher because after getting all the possible path, i could parse them and get the fastest one.. and using cypher to get those would be easier for me cause i'm using neo4j with nodejs..

Comment: Although to first get all paths between two nodes and then filter afterwards is potentially much much slower, because the algorithm can't be clever and select the best paths right away, i.e. take "shortcuts"

Comment: We probably should expose some more of those algorithms to cypher somehow.